# Photoswipe - thumbnails on fullscreen mode

Tags: javascript, photoswipe, jcarousellite

I'm having [jCarouselLite](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/demo.php) with photo thumbnails. When photo is clicked - it launches [Photoswipe](http://photoswipe.com/) in fullscreen mode. In this fullscreen mode I would like to have those thumbnails (jCarouselLite) at the bottom of fullscreen photo from Photoswipe. Those thumbails should also be clickable, but should only change big photo (quite natural behaviour). Do you know any existing solution? Or maybe I should consider other photo gallery and thumbnail slider? (It should be highly customizable). jQuery is allowed,

regards